# Using @onkeyup in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor, event-listener

So I'm making a simple app in blazor for converting some measurements. I have an input which should trigger a function ConvertUnits(). I want it to be triggered every time I type something in the input, but for some reason it is triggering only after pressing Enter.
What should I do to trigger the function every time I'm typing some number in the input?

Here is the imput:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control @(lengthValue <= 0 ? "bg-danger" : "bg-success")" @bind="lengthValue" @oninput="(e => { OnChangeValue(e); })" @onkeyup="(e => { ConvertUnits(); })" />
```

Here is the function:

```
    private void ConvertUnits()
    {
       result = ConvertLength(lengthValue, selectedLengthUnit, selectedTargetLengthUnit); 
    }

    private double ConvertLength(double value, string fromUnit, string toUnit)
    {
        Dictionary<string, double> lengthFactors = new Dictionary<string, double>
        {
            { "Metry", 1.0 },
            { "Cale", 39.3701 },
            { "Stopy", 3.28084 },
            { "", 0 }
        };

        fromUnit ??= "";
        toUnit ??= "";

        if (lengthFactors.ContainsKey(fromUnit) && lengthFactors.ContainsKey(toUnit))
        {
            return value * lengthFactors[toUnit] / lengthFactors[fromUnit];
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I think I tried every Event Listener that there is including @onblur, @onkeydown, @oninput etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to resort to key events.

Here's how to use the normal events.  I've taken the liberty of refactoring your conversion code by encapsulating it into a value object.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Metre Converter</PageTitle>

<h1>Metre Converter</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div>
    <label>Enter Value in Metres</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control mb-3" min="0"
           @bind="lengthValue"
           @bind:after="ConvertUnits"
           @bind:event="oninput" />
</div>

<select class="form-select mb-3" @bind="_selectedUnit" @bind:after="ConvertUnits">
    @if(_selectedUnit is null)
    {
        <option value="" selected disabled> -- Select a Unit -- </option>
    }
    @foreach (var unit in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Length.Units)))
    {
        <option value="@unit">@unit</option>
    }
</select>

<div>
    <pre>Conversion = @_convertedValue</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private double lengthValue;
    private string? _selectedUnit;
    private double? _convertedValue;

    private void ConvertUnits()
    {
        var number = Length.FromMetres(lengthValue);
        _convertedValue = number.GetUnitValue(_selectedUnit);
    }

    public record Length
    {
        private double _length { get; init; }

        private Length(double lengthInMetres)
            => _length = lengthInMetres;

        public double GetUnitValue(string? units)
        {
            if (units is null)
                return this.UnitValue(Units.Metres);

            var u = (Units)Enum.Parse(typeof(Units), units);
            return this.UnitValue(u);
        }

        public double UnitValue(Units units)
            => units switch
            {
                Units.Millimetres => _length * 1000,
                Units.Inches => _length * InchesConversion,
                Units.Feet => _length * FeetConversion,
                _ => _length
            };

        public enum Units
        {
            Metres,
            Inches,
            Feet,
            Millimetres
        }

        public const double FeetConversion = 3.28084;
        public const double InchesConversion = 39.2701;

        public static Length FromMetres(double metres)
            => new(metres);

        public static Length FromFeet(double feet)
            => new(feet / FeetConversion);

        public static Length FromInches(double inches)
            => new(inches / InchesConversion);

    }
}
```